# Code not going inside the Request method of REST get call using volley in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created a get method which return the json object. But when running it is not going inside the JSONObjectRequest method, and always returning null value. please help me with this

```
public JSONObject getCall(String url){
    final JSONObject temp=null;
    try{
    JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                JSONObject temp1;
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    temp1=response;
                    System.out.println(response);
                }
                public JSONObject getTemp1() {
                    return temp1;
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });}
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: You should use the interface to return data to the calling function or activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be temp is null while returning

```
public JSONObject getCall(String url){
JSONObject temp=null;
try{
JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            JSONObject temp1;
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                temp = response;
                temp1=response;
                System.out.println(response);
            }
            public JSONObject getTemp1() {
                return temp1;
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
});}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
return temp;
```

}

Comment: It is not null, when i call the same api using postman it is returning a valid value

Comment: have you tried this code and still you are getting the same result

Comment: don't make temp value final.

Comment: try now.. sorry, for the last mistake as final object can't be changed you got that error(cant assign value to final variable temp error)

Answer (score 0):

Try not using Localhost, instead use "10.0.2.2" for the URL you are requesting.